# Xamarin.Forms authentication, save logged in status after login, remember me

Tags: xamarin, token, xamarin.forms, remember-me

I'm looking for a good way for my application to know if the person needs to login (again) or not.

So meaning, if a person first uses the app, he needs to login. These login credentials are being verified by a webservice I've build. And after he is succesfully signed in, the next time he uses the application he doens't need to login again.

I've been looking around, but haven't found a clear solution.
I have read a few possibilities to handles this:

- Storing this in a local database
- Using the 'Settings plugin' from James Montemagno
- Using local storage
- Using KeyChain (IOS), KeyStore (Android)

It is not my entention to store the login credentials, only to remember if he has signed in previously or not.

Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'Settings plugin' from James Montemagno to store a Boolean value ( LoggedIn = true or false).

But you might want to add a but more logic to your app. If someone is logged in, they should have a token that they'll use to communicate with your server...this token should have an expiry date and you should also have a refresh token.